# SwiftUI doesn't collapse navbar when single non scroll item is in VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having an issue when I scroll that the navbar doesn't collapse to a small one, it only happens when there's an additional "non scrolling" item in the `VStack`.

The following code works fine

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
}
```

and runs as follows:

[image]

But when I add something else to the top level `VStack`, the navbar no longer collapses. So this code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            SegmentedControl(selectedSegmentIndex: $currentTabIndex, segments: [.new, .new])
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
}
```

results in this:

[image]

Is there a way to tie the offset of the scroll view to the navbar collapsing? Or any other workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collapsing is a special behavior of `NavigationView & ScrollView/List`. So if you want it, put everything inside of `ScrollView`, like

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                SegmentedControl(selectedSegmentIndex: $currentTabIndex, 
                    segments: [.new, .new])
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
}
```

Comment: So there’s no way to keep the segment control pinned to the top?

Comment: Putting everything inside a VStack (and the VStack itself in a ScrollView) breaks the behaviour of ScrollViewReader `scrollTo()`.

Comment: @Mr.P you ever figure this out? I’m having the same issue